# Convert Bouncy Castle certificate to Java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I need to convert a bouncy castle certificate(X.509) to javas x.509 certificate. How can I do this? I tried with this

```
 byte[] encoded = certificate.getCertificateAt(0).getEncoded(); // our bouncy castle certificate
     try {            
            java.security.cert.Certificate jcert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded));
            TLSClient.this.certificate = (X509Certificate)jcert; // our java certificate
       } catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown certificate");
```

I also tried with `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate.getInstance(inputStream)` but I couldn't use `javax` because some of the methods I use to call on my cert, like `getSignature()` and `getType()` doesn't work if I have use `javax`, so I need to use java. Do anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` instead of `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate`

```
 //get encoded certificate. I used the base64 content you provided
 //byte[] encoded = certificate.getCertificateAt(0).getEncoded();
 String certB64 = "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";
 byte encoded[] = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(certB64);

 //build the certificate
 X509Certificate cert = 
    (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
          .generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(encoded));
```

---

```
 //CN=*.google.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
 System.out.println(cert.getSubjectDN());
 //X.509 
 System.out.println(cert.getType());
```

Comment: I forgot to say that but we tried that earlier as well, but I get an X509Certficate object that is empty. The object exist but the information in the varibales are null.

Comment: Are you sure that `certificate.getCertificateAt(0).getEncoded();` contains a X509 certificate ? Could you add an example to your question (post the encoded data in base64)?

Comment: If I print certificate.getCertificateAt(0), I get: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate@c0640265. If I try to base64-encode it, I get: [B@5034c75a

Comment: You are printing the object, not the content. To print the content as base64 do this: `System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(certificate.getCertificateAt(0).getEncoded()));`

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I tested the certificate you provided and works perfectly. Review your code or update your question to show the full code involved. May be you have a conversion issue that I cant see

Comment: We noticed that we also got those working, but the problem is that some of the other getters was "not working". Like, getPublicKeyUsage returns null. When we used SSLSocket from the Java library we didn't get null from it, but now using BouncyCastle it seems like BouncyCastles socket doesn't read that information and therefor we lose it. Is there anyway to still get the same information from BouncyCastles SSL as in Javas? Our certDownload class: http://pastebin.com/qUf0mMa3

Comment: Do you mean `getKeyUsage()` ? This attribute can be null in the certificate. In fact in the certificate that you posted it is. The certificate is a set of data that is sent during SSL. Content does not vary if read with Bouncycastle or Java

Comment: Yeah that's true but when we went to Google.com with Javas SSLSocket, then we got it. But when we do it with BouncyCastle, we don't get it.

Comment: I have checked it and the reason is you are viewing different certificates containing similar data. Please review the serial number field. The certificate you posted yesterday has this serial number `15 aa a1 a5 01 18 45 72` and void `keyusage` and the certificate I get now in my browser has ‎`32 c4 31 24 6a a5 04 ef` and `keyusage` is defined. Probably Google serve different certificates depending on the browser or may be the hosting. This is not due to differences between Java and Bouncycastle certificate readers

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bouncy Castle (since ~1.4x) then likely you've access to the `X509CertificateHolder` in which case [`JcaX509CertificateConverter`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLpuuLx6vbAhUPLFAKHeGeAGgQFgguMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bouncycastle.org%2Fdocs%2Fpkixdocs1.5on%2Forg%2Fbouncycastle%2Fcert%2Fjcajce%2FJcaX509CertificateConverter.html&usg=AOvVaw12cmxPcBXtO5C2qh7ieYxY) makes it possible.

e.g. given;

```
private static final BouncyCastleProvider PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();

static {
    Security.addProvider(PROVIDER);
}
```

then;

```
// ... {

    X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
            .setProvider(PROVIDER)
            .getCertificate(signedCertificate);
// ... }
```